# YamlDotNet - Custom Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, yamldotnet

I have a .NET class which represents a RPC method call, like this:

```cs
class MethodCall
{
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
    public Collection<object> Arguments { get; set; }
}
```

I want to serialize a `Collection<MethodCall>` to YAML. I'm using YamlDotNet to achieve this.

By default, YamlDotNet will serialize these objects like this:

```yaml
methodName: someName
arguments:
- arg1
- arg2
- ...
```

I would like to simplify the resulting YAML to:

```yaml
someName:
- arg1
- arg2
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this? Please note that the arguments can be complex objects (i.e. not simple scalars).

Comment: Above public Collection<object> Arguments { get; set; }  add the following : [XmlElement()]   You have an array and Net automatically adds two tags for arrays.  Using Element only adds one tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by registering an implementation of `IYamlTypeConverter` that performs the conversion that you need.

Here's a possible implementation:

```cs
public sealed class MethodCallConverter : IYamlTypeConverter
{
    // Unfortunately the API does not provide those in the ReadYaml and WriteYaml
    // methods, so we are forced to set them after creation.
    public IValueSerializer ValueSerializer { get; set; }
    public IValueDeserializer ValueDeserializer { get; set; }
    
    public bool Accepts(Type type) => type == typeof(MethodCall);

    public object ReadYaml(IParser parser, Type type)
    {
        parser.Consume<MappingStart>();

        var call = new MethodCall
        {
            MethodName = (string)ValueDeserializer.DeserializeValue(parser, typeof(string), new SerializerState(), ValueDeserializer),
            Arguments = (Collection<object>)ValueDeserializer.DeserializeValue(parser, typeof(Collection<object>), new SerializerState(), ValueDeserializer),
        };

        parser.Consume<MappingEnd>();
        
        return call;
    }
    
    public void WriteYaml(IEmitter emitter, object value, Type type)
    {
        emitter.Emit(new MappingStart());

        var call = (MethodCall)value;
        ValueSerializer.SerializeValue(emitter, call.MethodName, typeof(string));
        ValueSerializer.SerializeValue(emitter, call.Arguments, typeof(Collection<object>));

        emitter.Emit(new MappingEnd());
    }
}
```

The converter needs to be registered into the `SerializerBuilder` and `DeserializerBuilder` through the `WithTypeConverter` method. Note that YamlDotNet does not provide us with a way to call the (de)serializer recursively, so we have to set some public properties as a workaround. This is not as clean as it could be, but still works:

```cs
string SerializeMethodCall(MethodCall call)
{
    var methodCallConverter = new MethodCallConverter();
    var serializerBuilder = new SerializerBuilder()
        .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
        .WithTypeConverter(methodCallConverter);

    methodCallConverter.ValueSerializer = serializerBuilder.BuildValueSerializer();

    var serializer = serializerBuilder.Build();

    var yaml = serializer.Serialize(call);
    return yaml;
}

MethodCall DeserializeMethodCall(string yaml)
{
    var methodCallConverter = new MethodCallConverter();
    var deserializerBuilder = new DeserializerBuilder()
        .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
        .WithTypeConverter(methodCallConverter);

    methodCallConverter.ValueDeserializer = deserializerBuilder.BuildValueDeserializer();

    var deserializer = deserializerBuilder.Build();
    var call = deserializer.Deserialize<MethodCall>(yaml);
    return call;
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to override how built in types are serialized? For example, I have a couple of ints that I would like to write out as a hexadecimal string rather than an integer. It looks like I can use `IYamlTypeConverter` to override the behavior, but then it will apply to all ints rather than the particular properties I want to be written as hex. There is currently no way to tell what property you are serializing, only the type.